# (Python Sqlite) how to strip single quotes and newline \n in a table?

Tags: python, sqlite

A Sqlite table is created

```
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Table1(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, URL varchar(500), Title varchar(500))")
```

Then some data is inserted into this table, data value all have a left single quote in the beginning and a newline character\n with a right single quote in the end. Like this

```
(URL) 'http://www.site.com/content/\n'
(Title) 'Mother's day gift card!\n'
```

I want to strip the first and last single quotes as well as the newline character, and tried this method, but it doesn’t work

```
cur.execute("UPDATE Table1 SET URL = rtrim(URL,'\n''), Title = rtrim(Title,''\n'')")
```

What’s the best way to strip the left and right single quotes and newline?

Comment: How does it not work?

Comment: OperationalError: unrecognized token: "'
''), Title = rtrim(Title,''
'')"

Answer (score 1):

In SQL, quotes inside a string must be escaped by doubling them:

```sql
UPDATE Table1 SET URL = rtrim(URL, '\n'''), Title = rtrim(Title, '\n''')
```